# Transforming R dataframe by applying function rowwise and create (possibly) larger columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to transform a dataframe (tibble) by using each row as function arguments and create a new column out of it, which is possibly bigger than the number of arguments. Consider the following example, where I have some sample observations:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

observations <- c("110", "11011", "1100010")

df <- tibble(obs = observations) %>%
    transmute(
        Failure = stri_count(obs, fixed = "0"),
        Success = stri_count(obs, fixed = "1")
    )
```

df is then:

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Failure Success
    <int>  <int>
1       1      2
2       1      4
3       4      3
```

I would like to take every row and use that for calculating a bunch of values, and save each result vector in a new column. For example I would like to do:

```r
p_values = pgrid <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = 11)

df %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    transmute(
        p = p_values,
        likelihood = dbinom(Success,
            size = Failure + Success,
            prob = p_values
        )
    )

Error: Column `p` must be length 1 (the group size), not 11
```

And get something like:

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 11
  p_values likelihood_1 likelihood_2 likelihood_3
     <float>  <float>     <float>      <float>
1       0      ...         ...           ...
2       0.1    ...         ...           ...
...     ...    ...         ...           ...
10      0.9    ...         ...           ...
11      1      ...         ...           ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually switch into `purrr` for this. The function `pmap()` will iterate by row. We use `..1` and `..2` to signify the first and second inputs, respectively. Using `pmap_dfc()` will bind the results by columns (dfc = data frame columns).

```
library(purrr)
library(tibble)

df %>%
  pmap_dfc(~ dbinom(..2, size = ..1 + ..2, prob = p_values)) %>%
  set_names(paste0("likelihood_", seq_along(.))) %>%
  add_column(p_values = p_values, .before = 1)
```

```
# A tibble: 11 x 4
   p_values likelihood_1 likelihood_2 likelihood_3
      <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
 1      0          0          0            0      
 2      0.1        0.027      0.00045      0.0230 
 3      0.2        0.096      0.0064       0.115  
 4      0.3        0.189      0.0284       0.227  
 5      0.4        0.288      0.0768       0.290  
 6      0.5        0.375      0.156        0.273  
 7      0.6        0.432      0.259        0.194  
 8      0.7        0.441      0.360        0.0972 
 9      0.8        0.384      0.410        0.0287 
10      0.9        0.243      0.328        0.00255
11      1          0          0            0
```

Answer (score 1):

This sort of workflow can be somewhat awkward with a tidyverse approach, as the data is not in a 'tidy' format.

I would come at it from the other angle, starting with the `p_values` vector:

```
likelihoods <- 
  tibble(p = p_values) %>%
  mutate(likelihood_1 = dbinom(df[1,]$Success,size = df[1,]$Failure + df[1,]$Success,prob = p),
         likelihood_2 = dbinom(df[2,]$Success,size = df[2,]$Failure + df[2,]$Success,prob = p),
         likelihood_3 = dbinom(df[3,]$Success,size = df[3,]$Failure + df[3,]$Success,prob = p))
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `transmute` or `mutate` expects the number of elements to be same as number of rows (or if it is grouped, then the number of rows for that group).  Here, we do `rowwise`- which is basically grouping each row, so the `n()` expected is 1, whereas the output is `length` of 'p_values'.  One option is to wrap in a `list`, `unnest`, and reshape to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider` (if needed)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
    mutate(grp = str_c('likelihood_', row_number())) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
         transmute(grp, p = list(p_values),
         likelihood = list(dbinom(Success,
            size = Failure + Success,
          prob = p_values
      ))
    ) %>% 
    unnest(c(p, likelihood)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = likelihood)
# A tibble: 11 x 4
#       p likelihood_1 likelihood_2 likelihood_3
#   <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1   0          0          0            0      
# 2   0.1        0.027      0.00045      0.0230 
# 3   0.2        0.096      0.0064       0.115  
# 4   0.3        0.189      0.0284       0.227  
# 5   0.4        0.288      0.0768       0.290  
# 6   0.5        0.375      0.156        0.273  
# 7   0.6        0.432      0.259        0.194  
# 8   0.7        0.441      0.360        0.0972 
# 9   0.8        0.384      0.410        0.0287 
#10   0.9        0.243      0.328        0.00255
#11   1          0          0            0
```